# Sass doesn't process Foundation scss files

Tags: angular, sass, gulp, zurb-foundation, gulp-sass

i'm using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for managing tasks for my Angular2 project. I create the following tasks:

```
gulp.task('css', function(cb) {
  return gulp.src('src/app/**/*.scss')
             .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
             .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/app'));
});

gulp.task('foundationCss', function(cb) {
  return gulp.src('foundation/scss/foundation.scss')
             .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
             .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/styles'));
});
```

The first task works with no problems, the second one doesn't work.
I get `foundation.css` file that cointains only a comment:

```
/**
 * Foundation for Sites by ZURB
 * Version 6.2.3
 * foundation.zurb.com
 * Licensed under MIT Open Source
 */
```

The source SCSS files came from [here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/tree/develop/scss)

What could be the problem?

Comment: If I look at the [source files](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/scss/foundation.scss), and open the `foundation.scss`, it contains a lot more than just a comment. What does the error log say?

Comment: I do not have any error log :(

Comment: and what is the css you expect? Are you calling any fundation mixins or function to get another code?

Comment: Here is the CSS i expect: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/dist/foundation.css

Comment: I've been watching the foundation `scss` files but I only see variables, mixins and functions. I think you have to use the `css` file or if you want to use `SASS` should do calls to mixins you need.

Comment: I want to use `css` coming from compiled Foundation `scss`, because i could edit them. But it doesn't work and i can't figure out the cause.

Comment: but mixins doesn't compile if you don't call with an `@include` from a CSS class. Or maybe I have not understood well what you want

Comment: I'm trying to compile `foundation.scss` that has a lot of `@import` and `@include` in it, that automatically load the other `scss` files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118439/discussion-between-blonfu-and-smartmouse).

Comment: As you can see I solved, thank you for your support ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding the following row to `foundation.scss`:

`@include foundation-everything;`

(`@include foundation-everything($flex: true);` in case of need of `flex` in your application)